# How to set value for class attribute using selenium and python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, setattribute

I need to rename a class to set a button as active using Selenium. I created a selector `/input[@value='deal']` and used execute_script:

```
"arguments[0].setAttribute('class',arguments[0])", button, "fancy_radio inline fancy_checked"
```

to rename the class. And for attributes such as value, name it works fine, but I need to change the name of the class that is at a higher level in the DOM (`class = fancy_radio inline`).

How can I change the name of the class? I suppose I need to build a selector that points to the class I want to change, but I can't create a good selector.

Python Code:

[image: Python Code]

HTML Snapshot :

[image: Chrome details]

Answer (score 1):

You need to rejig the position of the arguments as follows:

```
button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='deal']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','fancy_radio inline fancy_checked')", button)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this solution changes the value of the class inside the `fancy_radio inline` class and my point is to change the value of the `fancy_radio inline` class, not the inner class.